# Persisting certificates in docker containers

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, .net-8.0

I'm using Windows 11 Pro, .net 8 and linux containers.
I have my Web API project done in .net 8 using C#.
Having problems persisting the certificate.
Here is the actual GitHub repo => https://github.com/xmione/AccSol.
Here's my docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: API/Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    hostname: api
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - sql
    volumes:
      - "./AccSol.EF/Data:/scripts"  
      - "./certs:/certs"
    # environment:
    #   - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    #   - DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    #   - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
    networks:
      accsolnet:   
  accsol.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}accsolapi
    volumes:
      - "./AccSol.EF/Data:/scripts"  
      - "./certs:/certs"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AccSol.API/Dockerfile
    container_name: accsolapi
    hostname: accsolapi
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - sql
    # environment:
    #   - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    #   - ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+;https://+" 
    #   - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=5049
    #   - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=7040
    #   - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="P@ssw0rd123" 
    #   - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/certs/AccSol.pfx      
    #   - DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    #   - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
    networks:
      accsolnet:   
  sql:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}accsolsqlserver
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: sqlserver-linux.df
    #image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    container_name: accsolsqlserver
    hostname: accsolsqlserver
    user: root
    ports: # not actually needed, because the two services are on the same network
      - "14344:1433" 
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd123
    networks:
      accsolnet:   
networks:
  accsolnet:
    name: accsolnet
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

Here's my Dockerfile for AccSol.API

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
# Metadata indicating an image maintainer.
LABEL maintainer="solomiosisante@gmail.com"
USER root
ENV sa_password=P@ssw0rd123
ENV server=accsolsqlserver
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
#ENV PATH="/opt/mssql-tools/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"

# Update package lists
RUN apt-get update

# Upgrade packages
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get install -y inetutils-ping curl gnupg openssl

# Install Microsoft GPG key
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

# Add Microsoft repository
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# Update package lists again
RUN apt-get update

# Install MSSQL tools and dependencies
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev

WORKDIR /certs
# Generate the RSA key and certificate
RUN openssl genrsa -out /certs/AccSol.key 4096
RUN openssl req -new -x509 -text -key /certs/AccSol.key -out /certs/AccSol.cert

# Convert the key and certificate to a PFX file
RUN openssl pkcs12 -export -out /certs/AccSol.pfx -inkey /certs/AccSol.key -in /certs/AccSol.cert -password pass:P@ssw0rd123


# Copy the script to the container
COPY ./start.sh /start.sh

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

# Run the script when the container starts
CMD /start.sh

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5049
EXPOSE 7040

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
# Metadata indicating an image maintainer.
LABEL maintainer="solomiosisante@gmail.com"
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
# Set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
CMD [ "printenv", "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" ]

ENV DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
CMD [ "printenv", "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" ]

ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+;https://+" 
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=5049
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=7040
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="P@ssw0rd123" 
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/certs/AccSol.pfx      

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AccSol.API/AccSol.API.csproj", "AccSol.API/"]
COPY ["AccSol.EF/AccSol.EF.csproj", "AccSol.EF/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AccSol.API/./AccSol.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AccSol.API"
RUN dotnet build "./AccSol.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./AccSol.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AccSol.API.dll"]
```

And here's my AccSol.API's Program.cs

```cs
using AccSol.EF.Data;
using AccSol.EF.Repositories;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

internal class Program
{
    private static ILogger _logger;
    private static string _environmentName;
    private static string _connectionString;
    private static WebApplication? _app;
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        //builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://localhost:7040");
        //builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        //{
        //    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 7040, listenOptions =>
        //    {
        //        var config = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel:Certificates:Development");
        //        string certsPath = config.GetSection("CertsPath").Value ?? string.Empty;
        //        string password = config.GetSection("Password").Value ?? string.Empty;
        //        listenOptions.UseHttps(certsPath, password);
        //    });
        //});
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

        var environment = builder.Environment;
        _environmentName = environment.EnvironmentName;
        var isDevelopment = environment.IsDevelopment();

        builder.Configuration
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        builder.Services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddCors(c =>
        {
            c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        _connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("AccSol.EF")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();


        _app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (isDevelopment)
        {
            //DoDevelopment();
        }

        _app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        _app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

        _app.UseAuthorization();

        _app.MapControllers();

        _app.Run();
    }
    private static void DoDevelopment()
    {

        _logger.LogInformation($"Application is in {_environmentName}.");

        // migrate any database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
        // Important!: This will automatically create the database in case missing.
        //           : No need to switch to master database.
        //Start - Automatically update db from new migrations ====================>
        try
        {
            var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(_connectionString)
            .Options;

            _logger.LogInformation("ApplicationDbContext is initializing...");
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions);

            _logger.LogInformation("Trying to connect to the Database using sqlcmd...");
            // Use sqlcmd to run a SQL script, for example, assuming you have a script named "MyScript.sql" in the root of your project
            //var scriptPath = "MyScript.sql";

            // Modify the sqlcmd command as needed based on your SQL Server setup
            //var sqlCmdCommand = $"sqlcmd -S localhost -d master -U sa -P P@ssword123 -i {scriptPath}";
            //var sqlCmdCommand = $"sqlcmd -S localhost -d master -U sa -P P@ssword123 -Q 'SELECT * FROM sys.objects'";
            var sqlCmdCommand = $"/bin/bash -c \"sqlcmd -S localhost,14344 -d master -U sa -P P@ssword123 -Q 'SELECT * FROM sys.objects'\"";

            // Start the process
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = $"-c \"{sqlCmdCommand}\""
            };

            using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo })
            {
                process.Start();

                // You can read the output and error streams if needed
                var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                process.WaitForExit();

                if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Error running sqlcmd. Exit code: {process.ExitCode}");
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Output: {output}");
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Error: {error}");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("sqlcmd executed successfully.");
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Database.Migrate() has been called...");
            context.Database.Migrate();

            _logger.LogInformation("Database migration completed successfully.");

            //End   - Automatically update db from new migrations ====================>
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                _logger.LogError($"Database migration failed. Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }

        _app.UseSwagger();
        _app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
}
```

Edits:  I tried persisting the certs by mounting a volume and using dotnet dev-certs commands to create and trust it and use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variables to set the path and ports. I can easily do it in isolation=process but not in hyperv mode. And I'm using EF Core. I think EF causes this error because it tries to connect to the accsolsqlserver container but the cert is not persisted. I can easily do it in isolation=process but not in hyperv mode. Currently, I'm receiving this error:

```
ERROR [accsol.api base 11/15] RUN openssl req -new -x509 -text -key /certs/client.key -out /certs/client.cert
```

If I try and remove the openssl codes to create the certificates, I run docker-compose up in a .bat file that runs these commands:

```
cmd /c "dotnet dev-certs https -ep certs\AccSol.pfx -p P@ssw0rd123"
cmd /c "dotnet dev-certs https --trust"
docker-compose --verbose up --build
```

This is now my error when I do that:

```
accsolapi        |       Hosting failed to start
accsolapi        |       System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
accsolapi        |       To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

So my question is, how do you persist certificates in linux docker containers with aspnet core web api,.net 8 framework in Windows 11 Pro using docker-compose.yml file and Dockerfile?

Comment: Please be more specific than "Having problems...". What problems? What error messages do you see? What do you do when you get the errors?

Comment: What problems: If you read the post, it says persisting the certificate. What error messages: Errors related to persisting certificates like ERROR [accsol.api base 11/15] RUN openssl req -new -x509 -text -key /certs/client.key -out /certs/client.cert What do you do when you get the errors: Run and debug those three files and try to trouble-shoot the docker container, what else?

Comment: It doesn't matter what errors I get, they change if I try another approach. It all boils down to persisting the certs. I tried persisting the certs by mounting a volume and using dotnet dev-certs commands to create and trust it and use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variables to set the path and ports. I can easily do it in isolation=process but not in hyperv mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of racking my brains and hitting the keybord with my head, I found the solution.
First, in my appSettings file I needed to add a setting for testing the connection to the master database, before connecting to the application's database. This is because initially there is no application database and it will only be created by running Database.Migrate().
So here is my appSettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestConnection": "Server=accsolsqlserver;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd123;TrustServerCertificate=True;", //additional setting
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=accsolsqlserver;Database=aspnet-AccSol-4e738ad6-a4fd-4a62-8afa-6641a1ee333c;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd123;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
},
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "APIBaseURL": "https://localhost:7040/",
  "HstsOptions": {
    "IncludeSubDomains": true,
    "Preload": true,
    "MaxAge": 31536000
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Development": {
        "CertsPath": "./certs/AccSol.pfx",
        "Password": "P@ssw0rd123"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second, I've added codes in Program.cs for the certificates.

```
var config = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel:Certificates:Development");
string certsPath = config.GetSection("CertsPath").Value ?? string.Empty;
string password = config.GetSection("Password").Value ?? string.Empty;

builder.WebHost.UseUrls(_baseAPIUrl);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    //TODO: sol: these ports need to be in the appSettings file
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5049); // HTTP
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 7040, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(certsPath, password);
    });
});
```

Third, I made sure that these environment variables in my Dockerfile is in the final layer, including ports and certificate path.

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=build /src/AccSol.API/certs /certs

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=DockerSql
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5049;https://+:7040
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=P@ssw0rd123
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/certs/AccSol.pfx

EXPOSE 5049
EXPOSE 7040
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AccSol.API.dll"]
```

Fourth, I checked that the ports are also declared in the docker-compose.yml file. I read somewhere that it is not necessary to do so but, I still needed it there because if not, it will create new ports in Docker Desktop.

```
  accsol.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}accsolapi
    volumes:
      - "./AccSol.EF/Data:/scripts"  
      - "./certs:/certs"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AccSol.API/Dockerfile
    container_name: accsol.api
    hostname: accsol.api
    user: root
    ports:
       - "5049:5049"  
       - "7040:7040"  
    depends_on:
      - sql
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=DockerSql
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5049;https://+:7040
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=P@ssw0rd123 
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/certs/AccSol.pfx      
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
    networks:
      accsolnet:
```

After this, the api container (accsol.api) was able to connect to sql server container (accsolsqlserver) and it automatically created the initial data in the database by running my CreateInitialData.sql file.

So this is issue has beeen resolved for now but another issue emerges.
When I run docker run I was able to browse the api swagger page and run the methods without any problem. With docker-compose I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. This is another issue and I've already created a post regarding this in the Docker Community Forum. [Here is the link to that post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-file-dockerfile-and-launchsettings-json-file-create-many-port-bindings/139321?u=solomiosisante).
[image: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED]